# Couldn't find preset "airbnb" relative to directory

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to set up Enzyme (written by Airbnb) in order to run some UI tests in React. However, no matter what configuration I have (and I've tried several) I keep getting this error. I added a `.babelrc` file which has the following inside:

```
{
  "presets": ["airbnb"]
}
```

but it still gives me the same error. The `.babelrc` file is on the same level as the `package.json` file. I've searched everywhere online to see what could be causing this, but I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the error you're getting

Comment: The error is the title

Answer (score 16, accepted):

make sure to install the preset

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-airbnb
```